# С PHP-сессии в переменную jQuery - открываем модальное окно

Tags: jquery, php

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как реализовать логику.
При загрузке страницы получаю из сессии значение и помещаю в переменную с помощью PHP:

```
// Берём из ссылки ключ после ? и помещаем его в сессию
   $_SESSION['rf_sponsor'] = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

// Присваиваем переменной значение ключа
   $rf_sponsor = $_SESSION['rf_sponsor'];
```

**Что нужно?**
Когда значение переменной **$rf_sponsor** равно **0**, т.е. не присвоено - ничего не происходит, когда значение не равно **0** - срабатывает обработчик, запускающий модальное окно.

Есть вариант создать скрытый **input**, отслеживать состояние с помощью  jQuery, запуская модальное окно по результату:

**<input type="hidden" id="someinput" value="<?php echo $rf_sponsor; ?>" />**

```
(function () {
    var element = document.getElementById('someinput');
    if (element.value === '') {

        //тут запускаем модал
    $('#someinput').frameWarp({
        url : '//mydomen.com/login.php',
        width:1040,
        height:720
    });

    } else {

        //тут ничего не делаем

    }
})();
```

Но, может, можно как-нибудь обойтись без скрытого поля и более правильным образом? Помогите найти правильное решение.

Суть в чём, нужно сделать одновременно две вещи: передать ключ и запустить нужное модальное окно.

Пользователь получает на почту секретную ссылку с ключом вида **http://mydomen/index.php?a7wet1mfr50**.
При переходе пользователя по этой ссылке, заканчивающейся ключом, обрабатываем **$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']**, отсекается ключ и помещается в сессию **$_SESSION['rf_sponsor']**, а затем в переменную **$rf_sponsor**.

Но обработчик, использующий этот ключ, находится на другой странице, во фрейме модального окна, которое ещё нужно открыть. Передать переменную на ту страницу запросто - сессия, но ещё нужно запустить модальное окно с этой страницей - **что и пытаюсь сделать гармонично**.

Переходишь по этой ссылке **>** автоматом запускается модальное окно **>** используем переменную уже на другой странице:

```
@session_start();
$rf_sponsor = $_SESSION['rf_sponsor'];
```

Comment: Если некий html-код появляется по флагу - то это решается средствами шаблонизатора: передали флаг - шаблонизатор либо вывел, либо нет. Но трафик давно не экономим, так что скрытое поле в связке с клиентскими скриптами - очень даже популярное решение. Какой именно "правильности" хочется добиться?

Comment: Добавил подробнее выше, что хотелось бы...

Comment: Смысл не изменился. Ну разве что поискать разницу в значениях слов "правильность" и "гармоничность".
Поставлю вопрос иначе: чем не нравится вариант со скрытым полем?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, что не совсем понял вопроса, но что мешает вставить переменную из сессии сразу в JS?
Например так:

```
<script>
   var rf_sponsor=<?=$_SESSION['rf_sponsor'];?>;
</script>
```

И уже в jQuery (по "rf_sponsor") будет доступно её значение из php, т.е. сессии. После - делаем, относительно её значения, всё, что нам нужно - любую логику: открываем модальные окна, высчитываем и так далее.

Comment: Спасибо,Ваш ответ оказался очень полезен в моём случае.